# Cassandra compound clustering key and queries with ordering

Tags: cassandra, schema, cql

We use cassandra wide rows heavily to store per user time-series as they are perfect for that use-case. Let's assume we have a table:

`create table user_events (
user_id  text,
timestmp timestamp,
event text,
primary key((user_id), timestmp));`

What if clashes on timestamp may happen (same user can emit two different events with the same timestamp). What is the best way to tweak this schema to resolve that assuming we have an ordering for all events present (have a sequence int for each event).

If I modify schema the following way:

`create table user_events (
user_id  text,
timestmp timestamp,
seq int,
event text,
primary key((user_id), timestmp, seq));`

I won’t be able to do `WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY timestmp ASC, seq ASC` – cassandra does not allow that.

Comment: `WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY timestmp ASC, seq ASC` - This query is possible in cassandra (For your second schema) eg: select * from user_events where user_id = 'xyz' order by timestmp ASC; This will return with Ascending order of timestmp. If a user 'xyz' is performing more than 2 events at same timestamp then seq value will be maintained in insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

> I won’t be able to do WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY timestmp ASC, seq ASC – cassandra does not allow that.

You might be seeing an error because you are repeating `ASC`.  This should work:

```
WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY timestmp,seq ASC
```

Also, as long as you have defined your primary key as `PRIMARY KEY((user_id),timestmp,seq))` you don't even need to specify `ORDER BY x[,y] ASC`.  It will cluster the data on disk in that order, and thus return it to you already sorted in that order.  `ORDER BY` should only be necessary when you want to put your results in descending order (or whatever the opposite of how you have it defined is).

> What if clashes on timestamp may happen?

I think your extra `seq` column should be sufficient, depending on how you plan on inserting the data.  If you are setting the `timestmp` from the client, then you should be ok.  However, look what happens when I (using your second table) `INSERT` rows while creating the timestamp two different ways.

```
INSERT INTO user_events(user_id,timestmp,seq,event) VALUES ('Mal',dateof(now()),1,'commanding');
INSERT INTO user_events(user_id,timestmp,seq,event) VALUES ('Wash',dateof(now()),1,'piloting');
INSERT INTO user_events(user_id,timestmp,seq,event) VALUES ('River',dateof(now()),1,'freaking out');
INSERT INTO user_events(user_id,timestmp,seq,event) VALUES ('River',dateof(now()),3,'being weird');
INSERT INTO user_events(user_id,timestmp,seq,event) VALUES ('River',dateof(now()),2,'killing reavers');
INSERT INTO user_events(user_id,timestmp,seq,event) VALUES ('River','2015-01-13 13:14-0600',1,'freaking out');
INSERT INTO user_events(user_id,timestmp,seq,event) VALUES ('River','2015-01-13 13:14-0600',3,'being weird');
INSERT INTO user_events(user_id,timestmp,seq,event) VALUES ('River','2015-01-13 13:14-0600',2,'killing reavers');
```

Querying that data by a `user_id` of "River" yields:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM user_events WHERE user_id='River';
 user_id | timestmp                 | seq | event
---------+--------------------------+-----+-----------------
   River | 2015-01-13 13:14:00-0600 |   1 |    freaking out
   River | 2015-01-13 13:14:00-0600 |   2 | killing reavers
   River | 2015-01-13 13:14:00-0600 |   3 |     being weird
   River | 2015-01-14 12:58:41-0600 |   1 |    freaking out
   River | 2015-01-14 12:58:57-0600 |   3 |     being weird
   River | 2015-01-14 12:58:57-0600 |   2 | killing reavers

(6 rows)
```

Notice that using the `now()` function to generate a timeuuid, and then converting that to a timestamp with `dateof()` causes the two rows with the timestmp "2015-01-14 12:58:57-0600" to appear to be the same.  But they are not the same, as you can tell by the `seq` column.

So just a bit of caution on using/generating timestamps.  They might look the same, but they may not be stored as the same value.  Just to be on the safe side, I would use a timeuuid instead.